# remove unwanted space in between a string

Tags: python

I wanna know how to remove unwanted space in between a string. For example:

```
>>> a = "Hello    world"
```

and i want to print it removing the extra middle spaces.

Hello world

Comment: (If you use <pre></pre> tags you can force SO to show the spaces :) )

Comment: @Tim: And if you indent your code by 4 spaces, you save us the work of removing all the `<pre>`-tags used by people who don't bother to look up the SO formatting options.

Comment: Ah, of course, I forgot. (I'm very much a SO newbie, in terms of actually posting!)

Answer (score 49):

This will work:

```
" ".join(a.split())
```

Without any arguments, `a.split()` will automatically split on whitespace and discard duplicates, the `" ".join()` joins the resulting list into one string.

Comment: For me it worked with ```"".join(a.split())``` i.e. without giving space in quotation before ```.join()```

Comment: @NiraliAcharya that removes all the spaces, but the asker wanted to remove the extra spaces.

Answer (score 22):

Regular expressions also work

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', 'Hello     World')
'Hello World'
```

Comment: This worked best for me to remove trailing, leading and middle white space, and remove \n newline characters.

Comment: This is a good way to go if you are using Pandas, specifically `df['full_name'] = df['full_name'].replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)`